# getTraceAsString() printing out as one whole line

Tags: php, string, exception, stack-trace

I am using the php method [getTraceAsString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php) which will pring out my error messages like:

```
#0 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/AisisCore/Template/Builder.php(147): AisisCore_Template_Builder->_render_template_array(Array, 'navigation') #1 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Aisis-Framework/index.php(3): AisisCore_Template_Builder->render_view('navigation') #2 /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/template-loader.php(47): include('/var/www/wordpr...') #3 /var/www/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(16): require_once('/var/www/wordpr...') #4 /var/www/wordpress/index.php(17): require('/var/www/wordpr...') #5 {main}
```

As you can see is one giant string. The example they gave prints out the trace as separate lines. is there something I have to do to get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a string with line breaks, not HTML. Look at the source code of your page.

Either wrap the output in `<pre></pre>` tags or replace the line break with HTML line breaks.

```
preg_replace("/\n/", '<br>', $trace);
```

Comment: `preg_replace()` is overkill for that, just use `nl2br()`.

Comment: `preg_replace()` works great for further styling the output such as lists.

Answer (score 2):

I have made some function for ZF2 error log , along with formatting of, 
**$e->getTraceAsString();**

Hope this might help you.

```
public function Errorcatch(\Exception $e) {
        $log = "<div class='error_main'>";
            $log.= "<br /><b>Error Time :</b>" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s A');
            $log.= "<br /><b>Error Code :</b>" . $e->getCode();
            $log.= "<br /><b>Error Message :</b>" . $e->getMessage();
            $log.="<br /><b>Error File :</b>" . $e->getFile();
            $log.="<br /><b>Error File Line :</b>" . $e->getLine();
             $log.="<br /><b>Error Trace :</b><br />" . preg_replace("/\n/", '<br>', $e->getTraceAsString());
        $log.= "</div>";
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log')->info($log); // This line write the log file.
    }
```